# gcloud SDK: Unable to write file

Tags: gcloud

I installed gcloud SDK with `brew cask install google-cloud-sdk`

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-gke-cluster --region europe-west4-c

Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials)
Unable to write file [/Users/xxxxx/my-repo]: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/xxxxx/my-repo'
```

Now all permissions of the folder and recursive files are restricted to 600 (`drw-------`). Tried to reinstall gcloud but with no effect on its behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using macOS and I'm unfamiliar with it.

The `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` command should write to a file called `${HOME}/.kube/config`.

The error suggests that it's trying to write the credentials to `/Users/xxxxx/my-repo` and this is determined by the value of `${KUBECONFIG}`. Have you changed either `${KUBECONFIG}` or your `${HOME}` environment variable? You should be able to `printf "HOME=${HOME}\nKUBECONFIG=${KUBECONFIG}"` to inspect these.

You may be able to choose a different destination by adjust the value of `KUBECONFIG`. Perhaps set this to `/Users/xxxxx` and try the command again.

Ultimately, this is some sugar to update the local configuration file. It should be possible to create this manually if needs be. If the above don't work, I can update this answer with more details.