# Why gcloud container clusters get-credentials messes up my Linux user permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, gcloud

After the notification from google about deprecation of previous auth mechanism for Kubernetes client that looked like that:

> We’re writing to remind you that, starting with Kubernetes v1.25, you must install a new binary called gke-gcloud-auth-plugin along with Kubectl (and custom Kubernetes clients) for continued access to GKE Clusters. You may do this any time, starting now, and we advise you to do this before you start using clients built with v1.25 or greater, which is expected to be released in Q3 2022.

I have followed the new instruction for installing and configuring authentication with a plugin: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#install_plugin

But after the command `gcloud container clusters get-credentials $mycluster`
I received the following error: `ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) Unable to write file [/home/wls]: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/wls'`
And now my system user is messed up and I do not have permissions for my own home directory:

```
ls -l /home/wls 
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Templates': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Pictures': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/todo': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Scripts': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Desktop': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Downloads': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Resources': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Programs': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Old': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Documents': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/snap': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Music': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Public': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Videos': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/wls/Projects': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Desktop
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Documents
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Downloads
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Music
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Old
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Pictures
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Programs
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Projects
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Public
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Resources
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Scripts
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? snap
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Templates
-????????? ? ? ? ?              ? todo
d????????? ? ? ? ?              ? Videos
```

Did anybody face such an issue? For now, I don't know how to fix that because the permissions for files seems to be ok (if checking from root) but the user cannot access files anymore.

Comment: Ok, I have figured out that the problem was that my home directory has lost `execute` attribute after that, once I have restored it - it started to work again

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure out what's going on.
I have a custom KUBECONFIG and it seems that in this case gcloud behave strangely (based on [gcloud SDK: Unable to write file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63475089/gcloud-sdk-unable-to-write-file))
Once I have performed `unset KUBECONFIG` before executing `get-credentials` operation it has been completed successfully.
Now I can just return back my previous value for KUBECONFIG variable and use the content of generated kubeconfig file (/home/wls/.kube/config) as I want.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue after executing `gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTER-NAME`.
This caused me also ending up in an endless login loop on my Ubuntu machine.
As Viktor Vlasov has already pointed out, the solution to this issue is to run `ctrl + alt + F3` from within the login screen. Then execute `chmod +x home/YOUR_USER_NAME`. This will add the `execute` attribute to it and your system is fixed again.

In order to prevent this from happening again, unset the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable...
However, this can only be a temporary fix. I assume that gcloud itself has some internal bug that causes this strange behavior and should therefore be fixed.